# How to set a validation error via ajax?

Tags: 7, ajax, forms

I am using the formapi to create a form. On one of my fields I have an #ajax call. When the field is changed I call the function. I recreate the form and then replace the whole form on the page. This works fine.

When creating the form I have some logic that sets the form state to see if a field has a value. If it has a value then I show some more fields. If the value is not set then I don't show the fields. I am showing the fields by setting the `#access` on the field.

I need to add some validation on the form when the ajax call is triggered. I have tried adding the validation using `form_set_error()` in the function that creates the form and in the ajax callback but the error is not displayed on the screen.

Am I going about this the wrong way completely? How can I get the form error to display?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your form is modulename_admin_form() then you can add a function modulename_admin_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state).

In that validate function you can [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) from in that validate function.

Comment: So when the form is submitted the validation kicks in as requested. However when I do the ajax callback the form does not update.

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not update'? What specifically are you (or are you not) seeing?