# #ajax form_set_error

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm using the below code to query a webform field's value against database, and if the value exists, I want to use [form_set_error](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), however I can't, since it requires rewriting the page. I have found [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72530/setting-a-validation-error-via-ajax) but it doesn't have an answer, hence my question.

```
function tubitekuz_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_97':
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid > 0) {
        $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
      $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#ajax'] = array(
        'event' => 'blur',
        'callback' => '_tubitekuz_check_username',
      );
      break;
    case 'contact_site_form':
      $form['#submit'] = array('_tubitekuz_show_message');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

function _tubitekuz_check_username($form, &$form_state) {
  $username= $form_state['values']['submitted']['kullanici_adi'];
  $exists = db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE name = :entered', array(':entered' => $username))->fetchField();
  if ($exists) {
    $commands = array();
    $commands[] = drupal_set_message('Kullanıcı adı kayıtlı, lütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı seçin');
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  }
}
```

How do I go about that?

PS: drupal_set_message does its thing only when I refresh the page, whereas form_set_error doesn't do at all.

EDIT: I tried to replace the above with the below code:

```
function _tubitekuz_check_username($form, &$form_state) {
  $username= $form_state['values']['submitted']['kullanici_adi'];
  $exists = db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE name = :entered', array(':entered' => $username))->fetchField();
  if ($exists) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'tubitekuz') . '/js/tubitekuz.js');
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'tubitekuz') . '/css/tubitekuz.css');
  }
}
```

and in tubitekuz.js I am doing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var username=jQuery('#edit-submitted-kullanici-adi');
    username.addClass('err');
    setTimeout(function() {
      username.removeClass('err');
      }, 3000);
});
```

and in tubitekuz.css I have the below:

```
.err {
  border-color:red;
  border-width:2px;
}
```

however, CSS rules are not applied even though class is added. What is the cause of this? All I'm trying to do is use `form_set_error` with `#ajax`

Comment: what you're doing is calling some function while using ajax. And not rebuilding the form/wrapper. You need to use a wrapper in your ajax array or rebuild the form so drupal can display the error messages.

Comment: it would be something like this: $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => '_tubitekuz_check_username',
        'wrapper' => 'form_id'
      );
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#form_id', drupal_render($form));

Comment: Why do you want to use ajax in this case? validate seems adapted

Comment: Because ajax seems the only option for real-time check

Comment: validate actually can do it and without submiting the form. Or maybe you want to check something/data from the form you just sent?

Comment: I had no idea validate can do a real-time check (as in check as soon as the user blurs the field)

Comment: Actually validate will be faster, because you don't need to use ajax. See my answers with the code, it should do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't validation work only when I submit the form?

Comment: I may not have understood what you wanted to do, when exactly do you want to do that ajax call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25108/discussion-between-kartagis-and-namari).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
//playground.module

function playground_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_1':
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid < 0) {
        $form['submitted']['username']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
      $form['submitted']['username']['#ajax'] = array(
        'wrapper' => 'webform-client-form',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'blur',
        'callback' => '_playground_check_username',
      );
      break;
  }
}

function _playground_check_username($form, &$form_state) {
  $exists = FALSE;
  $commands = array();
  $username= $form_state['values']['submitted']['username'];

  $parents = $form_state['triggering_element']['#array_parents'];
  array_pop($parents);
  $element = &drupal_array_get_nested_value($form, $parents);

  if (!empty($username)) {
    $exists = db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE name = :entered', array(':entered' => $username))->fetchField();
  }


  if ($exists) {
  form_error($element, 'Kullanıcı adı kayıtlı, lütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı seçin');
  $error_selector = '.form-item.webform-component--username';
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($error_selector, theme('status_messages'). drupal_render($element) );
  // Use below commands if you want to display in message region.
  // $commands[] = ajax_command_replace($error_selector, drupal_render($element) );
  // $commands[] = ajax_command_remove('#messages');
  // $commands[] = ajax_command_before('#main-wrapper', '<div id="messages"><div class="section clearfix">' . theme('status_messages') . '<div></div>');

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  }
}
```

Comment: @vijayc85 while I appreciate this (it actually works), it does the check only the first time. Could it be a jquery version difference? Does #ajax call use jquery anyway?

Comment: I'm running it in standard Drupal 7 installation and it's working all the time. Might be something to do with form cache setup?

Comment: Maybe I need to clear caches afterwards?

Comment: not sure. can you try to check with minimum change and see if it works (i.e. if the form is attached to another page, try to load the form directly and see if it works?)

Comment: I did, it's not doing it there either. I'll try lowering the jquery version tomorrow (to check if there is a conflict) and ping you on IRC.

Comment: @vijayc85, as I told you on IRC, it's definitely a javascript file issue because in the console I'm getting `Unexpected end of input` and the problem goes away when I change the theme to the default, so it's theme stuff. I'll ask our designer to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be adjusted to something like:

```
function tubitekuz_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_97':
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid > 0) {
        $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
      $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi'] += array(
        '#prefix' => '<div id="kullanici-adi-container">',
        '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'kullanici_adi_form_login',
          'wrapper' => 'kullanici-adi-container',
        ),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      );

      // Check the form state to see if an e-mail address has been specified.
      if (!empty($form_state['values']['kullanici_adi'])) {
        $mail = trim($form_state['values']['kullanici_adi']);

        if ($account = user_load_by_mail($mail)) {
          form_set_error('submitted][kullanici_adi', 'Kullanıcı adı kayıtlı, lütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı seçin');
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}

function kullanici_adi_form_login($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi'];
}
```

You will probably have to play around with some of the arrays, etc. to get the correct values, etc.

Comment: I appreciate all this, but this doesn't seem to resolve my main issue of returning a `form_set_error`

Comment: It should, to use an Ajax callback your callback function should return part of the form. Then in your regular form_alter function you need to check for the presence of the data in `$form_state['values']`

Comment: I've edited my answer so it's roughly the complete code required. The part which will need checking/editing are `$form_state['values']` & `$form['submitted']`

Answer (score 0):

it would be something like this:

```
$form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => '_tubitekuz_check_username',
        'wrapper' => 'the_form_id'
      );
```

and this one in your ajax callback _tubitekuz_check_username, you can put your form_set_error before. be carefull you might need

```
form_set_error('kullanici_adi', t('your error'));
```

or this one if the first doesn't work (I don't remember for this case)

```
form_set_error('submitted']['kullanici_adi', t('your error'));
```

then this code to rebuild a part/entire of the form

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#the_form_id', drupal_render($form));
```

This should do it.

That's pretty much what I told you 2 days ago.

EDIT:

```
function tubitekuz_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_97':
      global $user;
      if ($user->uid > 0) {
        $form['submitted']['kullanici_adi']['#access'] = FALSE;
      }
      $form['#validate'][] = 'webform_client_form_97_form_validate';
      break;
    case 'contact_site_form':
      $form['#submit'] = array('_tubitekuz_show_message');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
function webform_client_form_97_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
  $username = $form_state['values']['submitted']['kullanici_adi'];
  $exists = db_query('SELECT name FROM {users} WHERE name = :entered', array(':entered' => $username))->fetchField();
  if ($exists) {
    form_set_error('submitted][kullanici_adi', 'Kullanıcı adı kayıtlı, lütfen başka bir kullanıcı adı seçin');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I still can't do it. I did add a wrapper, and I did both the former form and latter form of form_set_error (I put it before `$commands = array();`) and it still fires only when I refresh the page manually :S The code is at http://paste.fedoraproject.org/232924/45254221/ so you can see.

Comment: wrong wrapper, to get the good wrapper go to the html of your form and take the id of your form, it should be somehting like this: webform-client-form-97 (css id and class don't have underscore)

Comment: I can still have it displayed only when I manually refresh the page. Please see http://ur1.ca/mv1oc. There also is no change regardless of whether I place `form_set_error` before or after lines 26-27 :S

Comment: You can't actually do a form_set_error when it has been submited, you need to do it in the validation function.

Comment: You mean callback, right? Hi

Comment: I've edited my original answer, try it and let me know

Comment: I've just checked, I am doing it in callback.

Comment: No I mean you can't do it after a submit, you have to do it while the form is being validated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24958/discussion-between-namari-and-kartagis).